# Prove if $\nabla f(x_0) = 0$ and $\nabla^2 f(x_0)$ is positive definite, then x$_0$ is a point of local minimum

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb R ^n\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function.

If $f$ is twice differentiable, and there exists a point $x_0\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $\nabla f(x_0) = 0$ and $\nabla^2f(x_0)$ is positive definite, then $x_0$ is a point of local minimum.

Comment: You can use Taylor expansion

Comment: HINT: Taylor expansion at $x_0$: $f(x) \approx f(x_0)+(\nabla f) (x_0)\cdot(x- x_0) +
(x-x_0)^T \nabla^2 f(x_0) (x - x_0)$

Comment: I am not sure how to use that

Comment: Taylor expansion tells you than first derivative vanishing together with the positive second derivative(Hessian), all $x_0$'s neighborhood points have a function value greater than $f(x_0)$.

Comment: What is the general formula for taylor's expansion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In elementary calculus for a function to have a local minimum the following condition must hold around $x_0$
$$f(x_0+\epsilon )\gt f(x_0)\Rightarrow f(x_0+\epsilon )- f(x_0)\gt 0$$
By Taylor's approximation we have
$$f(x_0+\epsilon)\approx f(x_0)+\frac{df}{dx}|_{x_0}\epsilon+\frac 12\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}|_{x_0}\epsilon^2+O(\epsilon^3)$$
We can substitute the approximation of $f(x_0+\epsilon)$ to the definition of minimum
$$f(x_0+\epsilon )- f(x_0)=f(x_0)+\frac{df}{dx}|_{x_0}\epsilon+\frac 12\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}|_{x_0}\epsilon^2-f(x_0)\gt 0$$
$$\frac{df}{dx}|_{x_0}\epsilon+\frac 12\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}|_{x_0}\epsilon^2\gt 0$$
We can generalize it to n variables such as
$$\nabla f(x_0)\vec \epsilon+ \vec \epsilon^T \frac 12\nabla^2 f(x_0)\vec \epsilon\gt 0$$
Since it is given that $\nabla f(x_0)=0$ the condition reduces to
$$\vec \epsilon^T \nabla^2 f(x_0)\vec \epsilon\gt 0$$
Since the term $\vec \epsilon^T (.)\vec \epsilon\gt 0$ is always positive definite for every $\epsilon$ the condition for local minimum reduces to
$$\nabla^2 f(x_0)\gt 0$$

Comment: what would taylor's approximation be if f was three or four times differentiable? i.e what is O($\epsilon$$^3$) when we generalize it for n variables.

Comment: $O(\epsilon^3)$ means that the rest of the terms are bounded by $\epsilon^3$. If you write down thirth differential then you can write $O(\epsilon^4)$. It is just a technical notation.