# Proof of Second Partials Test

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, optimization, partial-derivative

How does one rigorously prove the second partials test without firstly assuming that $D(a,b)=AC-B^2$ that states the following: $ A=\frac {\partial^{2}f(a,b)}{\partial x^{2}},B=$$\frac {\partial^{2}f(a,b)}{\partial x\partial y}$$C=\frac {\partial^{2}f(a,b)}{\partial y^{2}}$

1. If $AC-B^{2}>0, A>0:$ $(a,b)$ is a local minimum.
2. If $AC-B^{2}>0, A<0:$ $(a,b)$ is a local maximum.
3. If $AC-B^{2}<0,$ $(a,b)$ is a saddle point.
4. If $AC-B^{2}=0,$ $(a,b)$ is inconclusive.

Best Regards,

Thank You

Comment: You'd better look closely at what you wrote in item 3. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Using the theorem of Taylor. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665046/on-the-hessian-matrix-and-relative-minima.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla When do you normally come across this proof (In real analysis or advanced calculus?)

Comment: Advanved (several variables) calculus.